# Getting upload process via Nginx + Unicorn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upload, nginx, rack, unicorn

I'm using Nginx to reverse proxy my Unicorn process for a Rails app that I have. I would like to be able to get a progress status (similar to [apache-upload-progress-module](https://github.com/sarniak/apache-upload-progress-module)) for file uploads. I tried to use [NginxHttpUploadProgressModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpUploadProgressModule) but /progress still routes to the Rails app so that doesn't work. I followed the steps in [NginxHttpUploadProgressModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpUploadProgressModule) so I'm really at a stopping point here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without seeing the exact configuration you implemented, nor debug log, it is difficult to understand what can be wrong.

I suggest you:

1. compile nginx with the --with-debug option and activate debug log with the error_log directive.
2. check the debug log for the /progress request and look the order of the tested locations.

It is well possible you are using try_files and your /progress location doesn't trigger because it is located after your catch all location. You can try to put the /progress location at the top of your server {} directive

Answer (score 1):

I am using it, have a

```
location ^~ /progress {
  upload_progress_json_output;
  report_uploads proxied;
}
```

section in the server block and it works fine, Rails never sees `/progress`.

Comment: Is there anything else needed in the nginx conf file?  Do you need a "track_uploads" section somewhere as well?  If so, what else goes in the block with it?

Answer (score 1):

Alright so, I figured it out with the help of both you guys (masterzen, and j-l). I didn't have

```
location ^~ /progress {
  upload_progress_json_output;
  report_uploads proxied;
}
```

but

```
location ^~ /progress {
  report_uploads proxied;
}
```

and masterzen's comment helped also as I had

```
location / {
  # blah blah
}
```

before the /progress. Thank you so much guys!!

Comment: Do you need a "track_uploads" section in your nginx config somewhere?  If so, where does that go, and what else goes in the location block with it?